# Combine points from separate tables in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm in a fantasy movie league (like football, but instead of players, you draft movies) and I run the website for it.  What I'm basically trying to do with MySQL and PHP is this:  List every movie from the current year (1) on the main page and have it show each movie's total points.  Each movie's total points are based on this formula:

```
metacritic + (imdb*10) + top_bottom + power(receipts,(2/9)) + ALL OTHER AWARDS POINTS
```

My issue is that all of the awards points are held in a second table, well two really.  One table is called "awards", which holds all of the award titles and point values and the second table, "awards_won", keeps track of all of the various awards that each separate movie has won or been nominated for.

I believe what I want to do is to calculate the awards points for each movie using a subquery based on whether or not "awards_won.film_nominated" and/or "awards_won.film_won" = 1.

This code pretty much does what I want it to do:

```
SELECT title,
       (  select sum(awards.nom_points)
          from awards_won
          left join awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id
          where movie_id = 25 and awards_won.film_nominated = 1
           ) as total_nom_points,
       (  select sum(awards.win_points)
          from awards_won
          left join awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id
          where movie_id = 25 and awards_won.film_won = 1
           ) as total_win_points,
       ( select total_win_points + total_nom_points) as total_award_points
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN awards_won on awards_won.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movie_id = 25 and movies.year_id = 1;
```

EXCEPT that I can't use "where movie_id = 25" in a loop if I want to do it for each movie... so that's where I'm stuck.  Hope this makes sense.

Here are the table descriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`year_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`release_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`metacritic` int(3) NOT NULL,
`imdb` decimal(2,1) NOT NULL,
`top_bottom` int(3) NOT NULL,
`receipts` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `awards` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`festival_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`award_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`nom_points` int(2) NOT NULL,
`win_points` int(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `award_title_and_festival` (`award_title`,`festival_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `awards_won` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`award_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`movie_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`nominee_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`film_nominated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`film_won` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `year_award_title_id` (`award_id`,`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

PS: I understand how to display array variables using a foreach loop in PHP so the SQL statement is my main issue.  Thanks in advance!

---

Sample data:

```
 INSERT INTO `movies` (id, year_id, title, release_date, metacritic, imdb, top_bottom, receipts) 
 VALUES (1,1,'All Is Lost','2013-10-18',87,7.4,7,5947690); 
 INSERT INTO awards (id, festival_id, award_title, nom_points, win_points) 
 VALUES (1,3,'Best Picture',4,16), (2,3,'Best Lead Actor',4,16), (3,3,'Best Score',2,8); 
 INSERT INTO awards_won (id, award_id, movie_id, nominee_name, film_nominated, film_won) 
 VALUES (1,1,1,'All Is Lost',1,0), (2,2,1,'Robert Redford',1,1), (3,3,2,'Hans Zimmer',1,0);
```

This works for one movie, I just need a loop

```
SELECT title, 
      ( select sum(awards.nom_points) 
        from awards_won 
        left join awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id 
        where movie_id = 1 
          and awards_won.film_nominated = 1
      ) as total_nom_points, 
      ( select sum(awards.win_points) 
        from awards_won 
        left join awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id 
        where movie_id = 1 
          and awards_won.film_won = 1
      ) as total_win_points, 
      ( select IFNULL(total_win_points,0) + IFNULL(total_nom_points,0)
      ) as total_award_points 
FROM movies 
LEFT JOIN awards_won on awards_won.movie_id = movies.id 
WHERE movie_id = 1 
  and movies.year_id = 1;
```

This would yield 8 total_nom_points, 16 total_win_points and 24 total_award_points for movie 1

Comment: can you give sample records and your desired result?

Comment: @Walter here you go:

`INSERT INTO `movies` (`id`, `year_id`, `title`, `release_date`, `metacritic`, `imdb`, `top_bottom`, `receipts`)
VALUES
 (1,1,'All Is Lost','2013-10-18',87,7.4,7,5947690);

INSERT INTO `awards` (`id`, `festival_id`, `award_title`, `nom_points`, `win_points`)
VALUES
 (1,3,'Best Picture',4,16),
 (2,3,'Best Lead Actor',4,16);
    (3,3,'Best Score',2,8);

INSERT INTO `awards_won` (`id`, `award_id`, `movie_id`, `nominee_name`, `film_nominated`, `film_won`)
VALUES
 (1,1,1,'All Is Lost',1,0),
 (2,2,1,'Robert Redford',1,1);
    (3,3,2,'Hans Zimmer',1,0);`

Comment: This works for one movie, I just need a loop `SELECT title,
(select sum(awards.nom_points)
from awards_won
left join awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id
where movie_id = 1 and awards_won.film_nominated = 1) as total_nom_points,
(select sum(awards.win_points)
from awards_won
left join awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id
where movie_id = 1 and awards_won.film_won = 1) as total_win_points,
(select IFNULL(total_win_points,0) + IFNULL(total_nom_points,0)) as total_award_points
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN awards_won on awards_won.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movie_id = 1 and movies.year_id = 1;`

Comment: This would yield 8 total_nom_points, 16 total_win_points and 24 total_award_points for movie 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
  SELECT m.id,
         m.title,
         sum(if(aw.film_nominated = 1,a.nom_points,0)) AS total_nom_points,
         sum(if(aw.film_won = 1,a.win_points,0)) AS total_win_points,
         sum(if(aw.film_nominated = 1,a.nom_points,0)) 
         +
         sum(if(aw.film_won = 1,a.win_points,0))  AS TOTAL_AWARD_POINTS
  FROM awards_won aw
  JOIN movies m ON m.id = aw.movie_id
  LEFT JOIN awards a ON a.id = aw.award_id 
  WHERE 1 IN (aw.film_nominated,aw.film_won)
    AND m.year_id = 1
  GROUP BY m.id
;
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d804d9/7

---

Use an outer join to show all movies even if they don't have any records in `awards` table.
This is an example using `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
  SELECT m.id,
         m.title,
         sum(if(aw.film_nominated = 1,a.nom_points,0)) AS total_nom_points,
         sum(if(aw.film_won = 1,a.win_points,0)) AS total_win_points,
         sum(if(aw.film_nominated = 1,a.nom_points,0)) 
         +
         sum(if(aw.film_won = 1,a.win_points,0)) 
           AS TOTAL_AWARD_POINTS
  FROM awards_won aw
  RIGHT JOIN movies m ON m.id = aw.movie_id
  LEFT JOIN awards a ON a.id = aw.award_id 
  WHERE ( 1 IN (aw.film_nominated,aw.film_won)
          OR aw.id IS NULL
         )
    AND m.year_id = 1
  GROUP BY m.id
;
```

and using `LEFT JOIN` (the order of tables is different here):

```
  SELECT m.id,
         m.title,
         sum(if(aw.film_nominated = 1,a.nom_points,0)) AS total_nom_points,
         sum(if(aw.film_won = 1,a.win_points,0)) AS total_win_points,
         sum(if(aw.film_nominated = 1,a.nom_points,0)) 
         +
         sum(if(aw.film_won = 1,a.win_points,0)) 
           AS TOTAL_AWARD_POINTS
  FROM movies m
  LEFT JOIN awards_won aw ON m.id = aw.movie_id
  LEFT JOIN awards a ON a.id = aw.award_id 
  WHERE ( 1 IN (aw.film_nominated,aw.film_won)
          OR aw.id IS NULL
         )
    AND m.year_id = 1
  GROUP BY m.id
;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d108/6

Please pay attention to additional condition in these two queries, without it they don't work as expected:

```
  WHERE ( 1 IN (aw.film_nominated,aw.film_won)
          OR aw.id IS NULL
         )
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! One question, is there a way to edit this so that it shows all of the movies even if they don't have any award points?

Comment: I've appended two examples to the answer how to do it.

Comment: Spectacular, thank you so much! Learned a lot from your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT title, IFNULL(nom_points.`value`,0) as total_nom_points, 
    IFNULL(win_points.`value`,0) as total_win_points, 
    (IFNULL(nom_points.`value`,0) + IFNULL(win_points.`value`,0)) as total_award_points
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT movie_id, sum(awards.nom_points) as `value`
    FROM awards_won
    LEFT JOIN awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id
    WHERE awards_won.film_nominated = 1
    GROUP BY movie_id
   ) as nom_points on nom_points.movie_id = movies.id
LEFT JOIN (  select movie_id, sum(awards.win_points) AS `value`
  FROM awards_won
  LEFT JOIN awards on awards.id = awards_won.award_id
  WHERE awards_won.film_won = 1
  GROUP BY movie_id
   ) as win_points on win_points.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movies.year_id = 1;
```

check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4afc1/15)

Comment: Thank you, this is great! Is there any way to add "total_award_points" to other fields in the select statement?  Like this: `metacritic + (imdb*10) + top_bottom + power(receipts,(2/9)) + total_award_points as single_movie_total` ?

Comment: No, but you can do this `(metacritic + (imdb*10) + top_bottom + power(receipts,(2/9)) + (nom_points.`value` + win_points.`value`)) as single_movie_total`